# How can I make night mode?

Tags: mode

I want to take automatic night mode to my website, because it's based on reading, and it's important to have dark background from 7 pm to 6 am. How can I do it?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, so I haven't tried anything